# Is there any solution for a group of people working on a git merge conflict

Tags: android, git, merge

Let's assume a group of engineers working on a big project, let's say Android.
They develop their own features and changes, and periodically merge AOSP.

Now problems come. Obviously there are going to be a lot of git merge conflicts. However how can the guy who do the merge distributes different merge conflicts to different people who are responsible for the conflict?

Comment: If you merge, you are responsible for the merge conflicts.

Comment: well, the truth is the merge one is a maintainer rather than developer

Comment: The problem is, one project includes different modules require different developer to resolve it